# Pass in argument to function by name dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, parameter-passing, argument-unpacking

Is it possible to dynamically set the name of an argument being passed into a function?

like this:

```
def func(one=None, two=None, three=None, four=None):
    ...

params = ("one","two","three","four",)
for var in params:
    tmp = func(var=value)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, with [keyword argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-37):

```
def func(one=None, two=None, three=None, four=None):
    return (one, two, three, four)

params = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
for var in params:
    tmp = func(**{var: "!!"})
    print(tmp)
```

Output:

```
('!!', None, None, None)
(None, '!!', None, None)
(None, None, '!!', None)
(None, None, None, '!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for passing dynamic parameters but those parameters are not key value pair arguments. You can create a dynamic

> list

and pass it like this in function call

```
*list
```

e.g.

```
def fun(a,b,c,d):
pass

dynamic_list = []
if True:
  dynamic_list.append(2) 

if True:
      dynamic_list.append(2)
 if True:
      dynamic_list.append(2)
 if True:
      dynamic_list.append(2)

fun(*dynamic_list)
```